# Getting a HTML template as a HTML string

Tags: html, angular

consider that I have several HTML templates and they have custom HTML tags. For ex: c-icon, c-text, c-button etc.

For some usecase([Display other content along with innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75234710/display-other-content-along-with-innerhtml/75234929)), I need to access c-icon tag HTML inside c-text and append it to some text so that I can render it with some other html text. In future, I may have another component called c-badge and even I want to refer and render.

Could you please provide any suggestions for achieving the same?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm narrowing down correctly.. are you asking how to fetch html elements and how to manipulate the dom? in that case there are plenty of answers as that also here on SO

Comment: ex: I have a c-icon tag in icontTemplate.html. I want to get the html from that template and append it to a string along with the other string in getString function. I hope its clear. now. If not please let me know.